# Erro ao iniciar IIS Express Web Server - Error 0x80070020

Tags: visual-studio, processo, iis

Após deixar o Visual Studio uma noite em modo *debug* parado em uma linha, não consegui mais executar a aplicação web localmente por causa de um erro no `IIS Express`.
Tentei parar o `IIS Express` e reabrir Visual Studio, mas não resolveu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme [essa postagem](http://davidsalter.com/2013/11/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error-0x80070020.html) de um blog:

> O erro de código `0x80070020` significa `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`, que no caso do `IIS Express` (ou `IIS`) significa que a porta que o `IIS` está tentando escutar está sendo usado por outro processo.

Para descobrir qual aplicação está usando a porta, basta executar o comando `netstat` no `cmd` com a seguinte sintaxe: `netstat -ao | findstr número_da_porta_que_está_pesquisando`

> O parâmetro `a` é responsável por exibir todas as conexões e portas ouvidas.
>   O parâmetro `o` é responsável por exibir o ID do processo associado com a conexão.

Executando o comando acima:

```
C:\Users\Daniel>netstat -ao | findstr 49286
TCP    [::1]:49286            Daniel:49286           ESTABLISHED     4280
```

Após descobrir o ID do processo, que é exibido na última coluna do retorno do comando, basta pesquisar o nome dele usando `tasklist`:

```
C:\Users\Daniel>tasklist /FI "PID eq 4280"
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
firefox.exe                   4280 Console                    1    601.012 K
```

Ou pode apenas matar o processo com `taskkill`:

```
C:\Users\Daniel>taskkill /PID 4280
```

Comment: Acho  mais simples parar a porta.

Comment: Como faz isso ?

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso foi o site default que estava rodando e usando a porta da aplicação. Foi só parar o site, aproveitei para executar o VS em modo administrador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]